# diferenciar dispositivos conectados a una pagina web que se están conectando desde la misma red

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, socket.io

Estoy creando una app de votaciones en nodejs, express y socket.io, pero no se como hacer para que un dispositivo desde el cual ya se emitió un voto no lo pueda vuelva a hacer.
Intente tomar la IP de la conexión y bloquearla, pero, ¿Qué pasa si otro cliente en otro dispositivo conectado a esa misma IP quisiera votar? ¿Cómo diferencio esos dispositivos o la conexión?

Comment: Las preguntas de este tipo no son bien recibidas. Por favor edita la pregunta y asegúrate de que cumpla los requisitos de una pregunta válida. De lo contrario no obtendrás respuestas o será eliminada.

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar el código de: lo que has intentado, el error o resultado obtenido y el resultado deseado. De esta forma será más fácil ayudarte. Saludos